# Weblogic, Tibco SSL with ejb3 :javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Failed to connect to any server

Tags: java, ssl, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x, tibco-ems

EJB 3
Weblogic: 10.3.x
JDK: 1.7.x

We are facing below error when we enabled SSL for existing TIBCO connection factories/queues. Our requirement was to enable SSL for tibco connection factories / queues.

```
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Failed to connect to any server at: ssl://server_name:44343,ssl://server_name:44343 [Error: invalid name or password: url that returned this exception = SSL://server_name:44343 ]
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._create(TibjmsConnection.java:1389)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection.<init>(TibjmsConnection.java:4127)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsXAConnection.<init>(TibjmsXAConnection.java:30)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsXAQueueConnection.<init>(TibjmsXAQueueConnection.java:29)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createImpl(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:164)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createConnection(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:253)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsXAQueueConnectionFactory.createXAQueueConnection(TibjmsXAQueueConnectionFactory.java:129)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.JMSConnectionPoller.getXAConnection(JMSConnectionPoller.java:438)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.JMSConnectionPoller.createJMSConnection(JMSConnectionPoller.java:2233)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.JMSConnectionPoller.connect(JMSConnectionPoller.java:808)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDConnectionManager.startConnectionPolling(MDConnectionManager.java:265)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.MessageDrivenManager.start(MessageDrivenManager.java:657)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.MessageDrivenBeanInfoImpl$DestinationResovler.activateNoneDDMDManager(MessageDrivenBeanInfoImpl.java:2356)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.MessageDrivenBeanInfoImpl$QueueConnectionHandler.handleNoneDD(MessageDrivenBeanInfoImpl.java:2798)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.MessageDrivenBeanInfoImpl$DestinationResovler.resolveDestnationWorkMode(MessageDrivenBeanInfoImpl.java:2289)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.MessageDrivenBeanInfoImpl$DestinationEventHandler.onDestinationsAvailable(MessageDrivenBeanInfoImpl.java:2112)
        at weblogic.jms.extensions.JMSDestinationAvailabilityHelper$DestinationAvailabilityListenerWrapper$2.run(JMSDestinationAvailabilityHelper.java:386)
        at weblogic.jms.extensions.JMSDestinationAvailabilityHelper$DestinationAvailabilityListenerWrapper.callOutListener(JMSDestinationAvailabilityHelper.java:402)
        at weblogic.jms.extensions.JMSDestinationAvailabilityHelper$DestinationAvailabilityListenerWrapper.onDDMembershipChange(JMSDestinationAvailabilityHelper.java:383)
        at weblogic.jms.common.CDS$DD2Listener.run(CDS.java:1264)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shared does show "invalid name or password" as the cause of the error, so I believe that is a good hint to what is causing the error.

Make sure the correct username and password has been configured both in the TIBCO EMS configuration file for the particular instance you are trying to connect to and on Weblogic.

The only other reason I can think of is if the ssl url is incorrect which I believe is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tibco instance 6.3 have known issue so they have to store username and password in instance.